# Find highlighted data in Excel Worksheet Programmatically

Tags: excel, xml

We have to process inbound client Excel files.  One client highlights changed data in yellow.  I have been asked to find the highlighted yellow cells, and import only the rows that have changes.

I am using Alteryx, but that is largely immaterial;  The problem is not how to code this, but how to find the relevant highlighted rows and columns in the Excel internal file structure.

I know that an Excel workbook is a zipped set of XML files.  I can copy the .xlsx file to .zip, and expand it, and process the individual XML worksheets, for example I can load ".\xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml".  In there, I can see the cell locations, and I can see some XML attributes.  If the cell has a style, it seems to get the s="" attribute.

I assume this relates to a style setting.  I can open the style sheet, but I cannot relate the value in the s attribute to entries in the style sheet file.  For example, I have a value of s="219" for a highlighted cell, but there are not 219 styles in the style file, so the s value is not an index.

Does anyone know how Excel files work 'under the hood', so that I can relate the worksheet cell data to the style data to find highlighted cells?

I am not looking for "have you tried an Excel macro?" or "use Python?" or other suggestions/guesses.  Please, with great respect to your time and expertise, only answer if you know about Excel's internal file structure and you know the answer to this particular, admittedly very niche, query.